# How can I see the input and output of an action in a workshop?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

When I select a workshop with <kbd>q</kbd>, I can see all options available for that workshop. If I select an option for which I don't meet the requirements, a screen pops up telling me the required input and the output for that option. Is there a way to see this screen for an option I *do* meet the requirements for?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a word? No.

There are a few caveats here (check the Status => Stone menu, for an example); but mostly you're just going to have to learn and remember.

Of course; very few jobs require special materials: most of the time the name of the job will tell you exactly what you are going to end up using. (Make stone cabinet, for instance, uses stone available to the workshop; and Craft iron helmet will use iron and fuel.)

Comment: I know all the vanilla jobs, the problem now is I've started using the Masterwork mod, and I'm trying to figure out what all those jobs are using up. It would also be nice to know *how many* of each item a job uses. It's difficult to learn, because even once you have someone do the job, you don't know what it has used unless you watch very carefully, which is hard to do in a fortress.

Comment: @SaintWacko: Looks like it's time to crack open the manual. ;)

Comment: Oh, yeah, I keep forgetting that's there, since it's a batch file. Right, time to do some reading.

Comment: I just made another discovery. If you view an item with k -> Enter, it will show all reactions involving that item. I've also discovered that the best way to figure out what is needed for a particular reaction is to simply look at the raws.